# Importing NetBeans maven actions into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

I imported a maven project from NetBeans 7.3 into Eclipse Kepler. But I don't know how to import NetBeans maven actions! Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
<action>
    <actionName>run</actionName>
    <goals>
        <goal>process-classes</goal>
        <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <properties>
        <exec.args>-Xmx120m -classpath %classpath foo.bar.Main ...</exec.args>
        <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
        <exec.classpathScope>runtime</exec.classpathScope>
        <exec.workingdir>/Users/....</exec.workingdir>
    </properties>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a netbeans specific file. Unless the eclipse (m2e) developers recognise the format, the only way for you is to manually convert to whatever format eclipse is using to store user's maven executions.